# Retrieving data from singleton in a more clever way ?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, singleton

I have some game data in my `GameStateSingleton`, which I don't want to retrieve every time explicitly with `[[GameStateSingleton sharedMySingleton]getVariable]`, so I asked myself whether it is possible to do something like that :

In the interface file of my class, `GameLayer` I set up properties and variables like `sharedHealth`.

```
@interface GameLayer : CCLayer
{
    int sharedHealth;

}
@property (nonatomic,assign) int sharedHealth;
```

and of course synthesize it in the implementation.

```
@synthesize sharedHealth;
```

In the initialization of GameLayer I would like to do something like :

```
sharedHealth = [self getCurrentHealth];
```

and add the corresponding method

```
-(int)getCurrentHealth{
   int myHealth = [[GameStateSingleton sharedMySingleton]getSharedHealth];
   return myHealth;
}
```

Is that possible ? From what I have experienced, I just seem to get crashes. How would I achieve my goal, to not always have to call the long method, as it always retrieves the same variable? There has to be a solution for this ...

Comment: It's crashing because you misnamed the getter method.  Drop the "get".  Otherwise, what you have is fine (though you might want to change it from "assign" to "readonly").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an instance variable for that. You could just write a shortcut function like this:

```
- (int)sharedHealth {
    return [[GameStateSingleton sharedMySingleton] getSharedHealth];
}
```

And where ever you need that value, you call `[self sharedHealth]`.

You could also use a preprocessor macro instead. Just define this:

```
#define SharedHealth [[GameStateSingleton sharedMySingleton] getSharedHealth]
```

And then simply use that when you need the value.

Note, that in Objective-C you don't call getter methods "`getVariable`", but simply "`variable`". Mostly this is a convention, but if you start using [KVC](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html) or [KVO](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) it's a rule you have to follow. So it's better to get used to it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just the repetitive typing that you're trying to avoid, you could use the old C way...

```
#define GAME_STATE [GameStateSingleton sharedMySingleton]
```

...and then...

```
int localValue = [GAME_STATE property];
```